# Laying out Radio Buttons on Image

Tags: html, css

I am attempting the following layout.

[image]

The radiobuttons are overlapped on teh images and the left and right buttons are vertically aligned in the center

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div class="images">
    <img class="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg" />
</div>    



<div>
      <div class="button-left"></div>
      <div class="button-right"></div>
</div>



<div class="navigation">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
  <input type="radio" name="op">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p6J9A/

Comment: What you want to ahieve? slider ?

Comment: You have put the HTML inside JavaScript panel at the fiddle demo. That was the reason I edited your question, but you rolled it back.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize how this works. The site gave me a message about some edit which dismissed as I hadn't made it

Comment: Yes Nucleo 1985 I want to design something like the Bootstrap slider

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you want to lay out some radio buttons in image, easiest way would be to create div with background image and then inside layout those buttons. So it should look something like that

```
    <div class="images">
      <div>
          <div class="button-left"></div>
          <div class="button-right"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="navigation">
        <input type="radio" name="op">
        <input type="radio" name="op">
        <input type="radio" name="op">
        <input type="radio" name="op">
     </div>
   </div>
```

And in css file you should declare something like:

```
.images {
  background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/dL3io.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I wanted to keep the 3 sections separate in the HTML. What I can do is put the buttons inside the div image tag. But adding the radio buttons too, is that even right?

Comment: Can you be more specific? This layout will make buttons and radio buttons on top of wanted picture. You can test it out on JS fiddle, just don't paste HTML code in JS section as you are doing in the link provided.

Comment: I am trying to design something like the bootstrap slider minus the fancy stuff. So I will have multiple images sliding one after the other. I tried what you suggested http://jsfiddle.net/p6J9A/5/ but it doesn't get me close to what I am seeking